# JS Promises - End of Chain Returning before Chain Step

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a promise chain that consists of database queries and API calls. I am trying to run these processes and then store them as objects that I can use in my views, but it appears that my chain is rendering the last step faster than the value can be pulled from the `stripe.customers.retrieve` portion, which is preventing me from restoring the object returned by that method. See terminal output section for example. It might be my misunderstanding of Promises, but shouldn't chaining call the items in a top to bottom order? Is there a way to prevent the last chain from rendering before the `stripe.customers.retrieve` finishes?

Promise chain:

```
var account;
var card;
var customerInfo;
var test;

models.Account.findOne({
    ...
}).then(function(_account){
    console.log('Here is the account: ' + _account);
    account = _account;
    return stripe.customers.retrieveCard(account.customerId, account.cardId, {
        function(err, account){
            if (err){
                return console.log(err);
            } else {
                return console.log(account);
            }
        }
    }).then(function(_card){
        console.log('Here is the card: ' + _card);
        card = _card;
        return stripe.customers.retrieve(account.customerId, function(err, customer){
            if (err){
                return console.log(err);
            } else {
                return console.log('Customer is returned ' + customer)
            }
        }).then(function(_customer){
            customerInfo = _customer;
            console.log('Returned value ' + _customer);
            console.log('Current card' + card);
            console.log('Current customer ' + customerInfo);
            res.render('pages/app/settings-billing.hbs', {
                ...
            });
        });
    });
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

Terminal Output:

```
Here is the account: [object SequelizeInstance:account]
Here is the card: [object Object]
Returned value undefined
Current card[object Object]
Current customer undefined
Customer is returned [object Object]
```

Comment: I think you are nesting two promises!

Comment: those stripe methods probably aren't returning promises and `return console.log()` doesn't make sense either. Where are docs for stripe methods used?

Comment: They aren't, here is the documentation https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#retrieve_customer. However I have a stripe call before`stripe.customers.retrieve` and it works in the context of my promise chain

Comment: Need to return promises for both stripe methods and resolve/reject them within the stripe method callbacks

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for the suggestion. Do you mind showing the change you would make in an answer below?

Comment: ok... found repo and they do return promises. Try getting rid of the callbacks though  ... See repo docs https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for finding that documentation! Changing it to a promise resolved my issue. Mind writing that as an answer and I will accept?

Comment: what did you actually have to do...just remove the callback argument?

Comment: yep, changed it to  `stripe.customers.retrieveCard(account.customerId, account.cardId).then(function(cardInfo){ })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `then()` on each stripe method instead of callback so you return a promise from each.

Have modified this a bit to keep passing one object through to the end instead of using global variables

```
models.Account.findOne({
    ...
  })
  .then(function(_account) {
    let data = {
      account: _account
    }
    return stripe.customers.retrieveCard(_account.customerId, _account.cardId).then(function(card) {          
      data.card = card;
      return data;
    });
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('Here is the card: ' + data.card);
    return stripe.customers.retrieve(data.account.customerId).then(function(customer) {
      data.customer = customer;
      return data
    });
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, ' '));

  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer: 
You need to call your promises in the way you are expecting your return values.
What you were doing wrong is that you have nesting promises. 
The idea behind is that you invoke a promise and when it's fulfilled resolve the value.

```
models.Account.findOne({
    ...
})
.then(function(_account){
    console.log('Here is the account: ' + _account);
    account = _account;

    return stripe.customers.retrieveCard(account.customerId, account.cardId, {
        function(err, account){
            if (err){
                return console.log(err);
            } else {
                return console.log(account);
            }
        }
    });
})
.then(function(_card){
     console.log('Here is the card: ' + _card);
     return stripe.customers.retrieve(account.customerId, function(err, customer){
         if (err){
                return console.log(err);
            } else {
                return console.log('Customer is returned ' + customer)
            }
        });
})
.then(function(_customer){  
                customerInfo = _customer;
            console.log('Returned value ' + _customer);
            console.log('Current card' + card);
            console.log('Current customer ' + customerInfo);
            res.render('pages/app/settings-billing.hbs', {
                ...
            });
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: *" think should be like this"* doesn't explain what is different or why you think your code would help.

Comment: I don't have a node environment to test it, but the concept is there!

Comment: code only answers with no explantion are of little value here

Comment: I made an edit to my answer. Hope I did explain it well this time!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but un-nesting the promises does not change the issue.

Comment: Can you debug this function `stripe.customers.retrieve`. Is it really, returning a value?